# UILabel doesn't change height in UITableViewCell in first scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using tableview on storyboard.

I change label's frame in `(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath` function.

then, after some scrolling, it can change frame. but, when I open my application, frame doesn't change at first.

sorry, can't post image till 10 reputation.
please help.

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
// get one row
Plan* planObj = [_planObjList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

// get custom cell info
LargeImageCell* cell = (LargeImageCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomLargeImageCell"];

cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg"]];
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
cell.titleLabel.text = planObj.planTitle;
cell.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
cell.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
cell.userNameLabel.text = planObj.getProducerName;

// title size
CGSize titleSize = [cell.titleLabel.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(300.0f, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin) attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: cell.titleLabel.font} context:nil].size;
// user name size
CGSize userNameSize = [cell.userNameLabel.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(300.0f, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin) attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: cell.userNameLabel.font} context:nil].size;

// set title size
cell.titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(7.0f, 230.0f, 306.0f, ceilf(5.0f + titleSize.height));
cell.titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

// set name size
cell.userNameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(7.0f, ceilf(235.0f + titleSize.height), 148.0f, ceilf(5.0f + userNameSize.height));
cell.userNameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
```

Comment: You can put your screen shot on any server, and share the image link

Comment: thanks. I added screen shot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

autolayout was problem.
I switched off 'Use Autolayout' on storyboard. then, it became clear.

thank you all.

Comment: omg, thank you for that. i spent about 5 hours trying to figure this out. you are a savior.

Comment: > Andy Shin : arriving here is my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the size initially through cellForRow method. You need to calculate the size and return it in the following delegate

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

To calculate size for a label based on the text use

```
NSString *labelText=@"some text";
[myLabel setText:labelText];
UIFont *labelTextFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:labelTextsize];
CGSize labelFrameSize = [labelText sizeWithFont:labelTextFont];
myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, labelFrameSize.width, labelFrameSize.height);
```

Comment: thanks.  
but, i know about cell's height. i mean uilabel doesn't change first.

Comment: thanks. I tried it. but I couldn't. I think this is storyboard's problem. I set short width's labels on cell in storyboard, then I can't. should I make labels by not using storyboard? fixing frame size labels are not problem in storyboard, but flexible frame labels have problems, I feel.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is using Autolayout you should do it with Constraints. To resize a UILabel with Constraints that should has at least that properties:
Line Numbers = 0
Line Breaks = Word Wrap

And about Constraints you should set in both sides, and one to top, DONT set to bottom!!

To set right size in the row u can use this code example:

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    id data = [self.listOfNews safeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

```
UIFont *font =  [UIFont fontWithName:K_FONT_AVENIR_MEDIUM size:textSize];

if ([data isKindOfClass:[NewsModel class]]) {
    NewsModel *news = (NewsModel *)data;

    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"7.0")) {
        CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(cellTextWidth, MAXFLOAT);
        CGSize textRect = [news.title sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:constraintSize];

        return textRect.height + paddingTopAndBottom;
    } else {
        CGRect textRect = [news.title boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(cellTextWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                                   options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font}
                                                   context:nil];

        return textRect.size.height + paddingTopAndBottom;
    }
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: thanks. i want to change uilabel's frame at first. could you check screen shot?

Comment: Usually the method cellForRowAtIndexPath is used to set cell identifier, to build the elements in the correct is use the method willDisplayCell. My suggestion is to use the willDisplayCell method or use autolayout (using constraint is much better).
Are u using xib or storyboard? Which ios are u developing?

Comment: thanks to your response. I'm using storyboard on ios7. I tried to use willDisplayCell but I couldn't change. I'll try to use autolayout. Do you know some examples?

Answer (score 0):

Try resizing frames in [willDisplayCell](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3awillDisplayCell%3aforRowAtIndexPath%3a) delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

Remember these steps in order to have `UILabel` to change size:

1) If you have a Custom `UITableViewCell`, switch off AutoLayout on elements of the cell

2) Use `heightForRowAtIndex` protocol method to change the height

3) Set the `numberOfLines` = 0 for the `UILabel` inside the cell

4) If this does not work re-set the frame ( I found that this happens when you are trying to enlarge a UILabel in some "far" end of the cell)

Examples

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 GeneralCell* cell      = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"GeneralCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[GeneralCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"GeneralCell"];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
    /////// USE the following block if still in trouble 
    CGRect frame = cell.label.frame;      
    [cell.label setFrame:frame];
    [cell.label sizeToFit]; // this should not be necessary in general
    ///////////
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {
    NSString     *detail   = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"YOUR TEXT]];

    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize = [detail boundingRectWithSize:constraintSize
                                            options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                         attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE]}
                                            context:nil].size;


    float h = (fmod((int)labelSize.height ,2) == 0) ? labelSize.height : labelSize.height+1;
    CGFloat height = MAX(h, 30.0f);
    elemento = nil;
    detail   = nil;
    return height + (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2);
}
```